# How to detect pubnub is not reachable

Tags: android, pubnub

I am using pubnub in my platform(client and server). I push messages from server to client through pubnub. Whenever client fail subscribing to a pubnub channel because of either pubnub service not reachable because of local proxy or any error other than the internet availability, I need to fallback on to a traditional heartbeat approach over HTTP to reach my platform servers. I have gone through PubnubError.class but it have many error codes defined. Can you please categorize and list out which errors suit my requirement ?

Comment: Not really certain what the issue is. What do you mean heartbeat approach over HTTP? You likely would use heartbeat over HTTP, but just not sure what you are trying to accomplish. But PubNub SDKs have error handling and connection retry on failure built in.

Comment: Let me know if this KB article is helpful: https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/142/how-do-i-check-network-connectivity

Comment: Hi Craig, There would be an interval based monitor which would send request to server  for getting pending messages/updates. For eg: if the interval is 10min then monitor will request server very 10min for getting updates. This is a fallback if client fails subscribing to pubnub.

Answer (score 1):

PubNub SDKs have error handling and connection retry on failure built in. Please review the PubNub KB article, [How do I check network connectivity](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/142/how-do-i-check-network-connectivity).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you need correctly, you can implement Craig's method. You can use any HTTP library for android to make a GET request to http://pubsub.pubnub.com/time/0 from the client. You can designate a timeout, say a few seconds, before you can make a conclusion that PubNub isn't reachable from that client. If there is no response from that URL in a reasonable amount of time, you can fallback to your other method of connecting a client to your platform servers.

Comment: Hi Adam, I think the approach Craig and you have mentioned cannot really inform if the failure is due to unavailability.I wrote a 5min wake up alarm which will try to subscribe to pubnub to ensure the device is live. This is most useful if the app process got killed for some reason. Whenever subscription fails I get a pubnub error callback with an error code. So now I need to decide if the error is due to pubnub unavailability and not due to a connection failure. if its due to a network error then I wait for connectivity and perform a resubscribe else I need to fallback to heartbeats which sen

Comment: d HTTP request to my server after a predefined interval. if pubnub subscription is successful after some time then I will make the pubnub channel as active for communication.So if the error codes are described then my problem is solved. Right now there are a bunch of error codes in PunbnubError class. None of them have scenarios and descriptions . Hope I made it clear.

Comment: *Whenever subscription fails I get a pubnub error callback with an error code. So now I need to decide if the error is due to pubnub unavailability and not due to a connection failure.* This will not be the case. If it is, do tell us. And which PubNub SDKs/versions are you using?